# Running a program as administrator first time only

Tags: windows, installation, administrator

I'm working on software which is deployed onto a Windows Standard Embedded 7 platform. It makes use of inpout32.dll, a popular library for reading and writing from/to the parallel port. This library is a bit sneaky. Rather than being installed via a setup program, it lazily installs - when it loads and a call is made, it looks at the hardware and picks a driver which is part of the program's resource. This is then copied to the windows driver directory.

The problem is that this copy will not succeed if the program is not run as administrator. And the software just dies. So I am searching for an elegant solution that doesn't involve turning off User Account Control (would that even work?). Indicating in the manifest that the program should run in administrator mode would be one way, but this pops up a dialog and I wouldn't want that to happen every time. Is there a way to specify "run as admin only once"?

Assuming there is not, what suggestions could you give me?

Comment: Make a proper  installer for the library.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't control the code, you need to train the users. I have this with some old apps I use. I run them once as admin so they update the registry or whatever it is they need to do, and then never again.

If you wrote this app, here is a way to deal with it. Write a helper exe that does the thing that needs elevation. When the app runs, check to see if whatever you need to be done has been done yet or not (eg registry key exists or the like, something you can check without being elevated). If not:

- put up a dialog telling the user that [whatever] needs to be done before [some, any, the ABC] functionality will work. Have a UAC shield on the OK button. Depending on the users, tell them that if they don't say OK to the upcoming UAC dialog they will not get their functionality.
- on OK, launch the helper exe - it should have an embedded manifest needing elevation. There are ways to launch it elevated from your code but why bother, this thing's entire purpose is to do an admin thing
- the helper does its thing and then exits. For your specific case, make a call that you know will cause the lazy loading, I guess.

The main app was never elevated and the user knew what was happening and the UAC prompt was not unexpected.

Comment: do you have any resources on what exactly needs to be done to elevate the application once the user has done the initial "Run as Administrator"? My app gets Admin approval every time its opened. I'd like to only require that once.

Comment: that's a different question. Chances are either a manifest is causing that, or a policy set when windows told you it "may not have worked properly" and offered to relaunch it elevated.

Comment: After doing some research I think I figured out my issue: I was creating folders and files in my app's installation directory on the C: drive rather than creating data in permissive locations. Looking at how other programs organize their logs, configs, and settings it looks like they create log files in the temp dir and user specific data in the user directory. I haven't finished relocating the data, but decoupling it from my installation directory should solve my permissions problem and follow standard application practices.

Answer (score 0):

I liked @Kate Gregory 's answer, but decided to try something else first. This was to  write an installer helper that would silently call one of the inpout32 functions on the Install() override. Since this was done with admin privileges it happily copied the embedded driver to system32, and voila!